# Multi-Level Pie Charts?

Tags: google-visualization

I'd like to make a chart which looks something like this:

[image]

It's essentially a pie chart which is broken down into multiple levels.

Is making something like this possible with the Google Charts API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Google Charts, no.  However d3js can do it.  They call it [Sunburst Charts](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063423)